# Custom Object set to null after adding to combobox

Tags: object, javafx, combobox, nullpointerexception, abstract

I have created an javafx gui. I also have a custom class, which i use to create an object of that class everytime the add object button is pressed.
when i create a object of the class and print the object to the console the toString() method is called. but when i add the object a combobox and select it java throws a NullPointerException .I used the setOnAction method for the combobox but it doesnt even look at the handle method. Can anyone see whats going on in the stack trace?

The martian class is an abstract class. Martians are either red or green.

```
protected ComboBox<Martian> currentMartians = new ComboBox<>(); 

public class MartianSelectorHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside combobox handler");

        Martian m = (Martian) currentMartians.getValue();
        txtaResults.setText(m.toString());

    }

public Pane buildRightPane(){
    VBox leftPane = new VBox();
    leftPane.setPadding(new Insets(15,5,5,0));
    leftPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    Label label = new Label("Curent Martians");
    currentMartians.setPromptText("Martians");
    leftPane.getChildren().addAll(label,currentMartians);

    MartianSelectorHandler comboBox = new MartianSelectorHandler();
    currentMartians.setOnAction(comboBox);
    return leftPane;
}
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at martian_stuff.Martian.equals(Martian.java:20)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:385)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:348)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1400)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:260)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:224)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$315/1947016627.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
```

the Martian class is a jar file. but the equals method shoud look something like

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    //boolean returnValue = ((getId() == ((Martian) o).getId())); ? true : false);
    return ((getId() == ((Martian) o).getId()));
}
```

These methods add to the combo box

```
    public Pane buildRow2(){
    GridPane row2 = new GridPane();
    row2.setHgap(10);
    row2.setVgap(10);
    row2.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Button addGM = new Button("Add GM");
    addGM.setOnAction(e->{
        System.out.println("Adding Green Martian");
        int newId = Integer.parseInt(txtfId1.getText());
        int newVolume = Integer.parseInt(txtfVolume.getText());
        GreenMartian gm = new GreenMartian(newId);
        gm.setVolume(newVolume);

        if (mm.addMartian(gm) == true){
            mm.addMartian(gm);
            currentMartians.getItems().add(gm);
            txtaResults.appendText("Green Martian ID: " + newId + " added.\n");
        }
        else{System.out.println("Martian not added");}

    });

    Button addRM = new Button("Add RM");
    addRM.setOnAction(e->{
        System.out.println("Adding Red Martian");
        int newId = Integer.parseInt(txtfId1.getText());
        int newVolume = Integer.parseInt(txtfVolume.getText());
        RedMartian rm = new RedMartian(newId);
        rm.setVolume(newVolume);
        if (mm.addMartian(rm) == true){
            mm.addMartian(rm);
            currentMartians.getItems().add(rm);
            txtaResults.appendText("Red Martian ID: " + newId + " added.\n");
        }
        else{
            txtaResults.appendText("**Martian not added. Duplicate ID.**");
            System.out.println("Cant add");
        }
    });

    Button groupSpeak = new Button("Group Speak");
    groupSpeak.setOnAction(e->{
        String speak = mm.groupSpeak();
        txtaResults.setText(speak+"\n");
    });

    Button groupTele = new Button("Group Teleport");
    Label stringDest = new Label("Enter Destination: ");
    txtfDest = new TextField();
    stringDest.setVisible(false);
    txtfDest.setVisible(false);
    Button okay1 = new Button("Okay!");
    okay1.setOnAction(e->{
        if(txtfDest != null)
            txtaResults.setText(mm.groupTeleport(txtfDest.getText())+"\n");
        stringDest.setVisible(false);
        txtfDest.setVisible(false);
        okay1.setVisible(false);

    });
    okay1.setVisible(false);

    groupTele.setOnAction(e->{
        stringDest.setVisible(true);
        txtfDest.setVisible(true);
        okay1.setVisible(true);


    });
    row2.add(addGM, 0, 0);
    row2.add(addRM,1,0);
    row2.add(groupSpeak,0,1);
    row2.add(groupTele, 1,1);
    row2.add(stringDest,2,0);
    row2.add(txtfDest, 2,1);
    row2.add(okay1, 2, 2);

    return row2;

}
```

Comment: The error is coming from line 20 of Martian.java. Can you show that class and indicate which line is line 20?

Comment: its actually a jar file given by the proffesor.

Comment: i have a copy of what the code should look like i believe its the equals method

Comment: You presumably haven't initialized some field in `Martian` that should be initialized.

Comment: Are you adding any `null` values to the combo box?

Comment: every martian that created must have an id and volume if not specified is automatically 1. those are the only fields associated with the class.

Comment: no i didnt set any thing to null just added the objects as they were created

Comment: Looking at the source code for `MultipleSelectionModelBase`, the only way I can see you getting that stack trace is by putting `null` into the combo box. At least show how you populate the combo box.